# Teradata Qualify Function Not Working Correctly

Tags: sql, teradata

to put it simply I have table a which looks like...

```
ID   |  Start_Date      
1234 |  9/1/2017
```

table b has payment dates and amounts that correspond to the ID from table a. table b looks like..

```
ID   |  Recd_Date  |  Tran_Code  | Total_Recd  
1234 |  10/2/2017  |    173      | $100
1234 |  11/1/2017  |    173      | $200
```

I'm trying to use the Qualify function to show the first recd_date and amount from table b that occurred after the Start_Date from table a.  So far I have the following code below.  the code works but for some reason it shows the 11/1/2017.

```
SELECT 
a.ID,
a.Start_Date,
b.Recd_Dt,
b.Total_Recd,
b.Tran_ID
FROM
(SELECT ID, START_DATE FROM tbl) a
LEFT JOIN 
(SELECT ID, Recd_Dt, tran_ID, Total_Recd
FROM tbl b
WHERE Tran_ID = '173' AND Total_Recd > 0
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Recd_Dt)=1
)b
ON a.ID = b.ID AND b.Recd_Dt >= a.Start_Date

Where a.ID = '1234'
```

the code runs, but for some reason I am showing null values for the b table columns. If I change the Qualify line to..

```
QUALIFY ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY ID ORDER BY Recd_Dt ASC)=1
```

I still get a null value,  If I change it to DESC order I get the 11/1/2017 entry.

What do I need to do to get the 10/2/2017 line?

Comment: You're using a `LEFT JOIN`, are you certain that there are *any* matching records for the cases where you get `NULL`s in `b`?  *(Note that the join predicate `b.Recd_Dt >= a.Start_Date` is applied **after** the ROW_NUMBER() qualification...)*

Comment: Can you elaborate on the number of rows and the number of rows per ID in both tables? And answer the question on your previous post:  
Is it possible to have additional rows in table a for the same ID? If yes, how to deal with those?

Answer (score 1):

You're applying the `QUALIFY` ***before*** the `LEFT JOIN`.  This means that you're finding ***one*** record in the table *(per `id`)*, then joining that on to `a`.

Apply the `QUALIFY` ***after*** the `LEFT JOIN`...

```
SELECT 
    a.ID,
    a.Start_Date,
    b.Recd_Dt,
    b.Total_Recd,
    b.Tran_ID
FROM
(
    SELECT ID, START_DATE FROM tbl
)
    a
LEFT JOIN 
(
    SELECT ID, Recd_Dt, tran_ID, Total_Recd
    FROM tbl b
    WHERE Tran_ID = '173' AND Total_Recd > 0
)
    b
        ON  b.ID       = a.ID
        AND b.Recd_Dt >= a.Start_Date
WHERE
    a.ID = '1234'
QUALIFY
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.Recd_Dt) = 1
```

Comment: Thanks this is perfect. I figured It was something dumb I was doing.  Is it possible to add a third table and use the qualify function?  Lets say the table c contains the same fields, and I would need to only show the first record c.Recd_Dt >= a.Start_Date.  Is this a possibility?

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY a.ID ORDER BY b.Recd_Dt, c.Recd_Dt) = 1`

Comment: Be careful though, the first join with `>=` will join "x" records to each record in `a` and then next join with another `>=` will join "y" records to each record in `b`, then filter it all back down to one record per record in `a`.  If you're only filtering small volumes, that's okay.  But if the joins have 1000 matches that are then filtered to one, your introduction of `c` makes that `1000 * 1000 = 1,000,000`...  Instead, just nest it all.  `SELECT blah FROM (your query with one QUALIFY already) LEFT JOIN blah QUALIFY blah`

Comment: If you fancy explain in ***absolute detail*** exactly how the data is structured, you might be able to do this with `LEAD()` instead of using a join.  But I can't help you with that without knowing in *intricate detail* how the data is structured.

Comment: Wow thanks so much, I didn't realize you could add multiple tables in a qualify statement.  That solves a lot of my issues!

Comment: Think of it this way, you join all your tables into one big fat juicy table, then you push the results through `ROW_NUMBER()` in some fancy pants way.  It doesn't matter how the big fat juicy table was made, or how many JOINs or source tables there were...  *(Feel free to upvote and/or accept)*